# Matlab, can the data cursor value RGB be used as a variable?

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to use the RGB value given from the data cursor of an uploaded image as a variable?

for instance

if RGB = 9 28 90
    (plot elsewhere)
end

Answer (score 0):

If you'd read the documentation on data cursor you'd find it easily:

- [Exporting Data Value to Workspace Variable](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/data-cursor-displaying-data-values-interactively.html#f4-44319)

[image]